# Calibre ignores headings from docx and html

Tags: calibre, table-of-contents

After some update, Calibre began to ignore the document's structure while converting `docx` or `htm` to `epub` and `mobi`. Before that, everything was OK, so I could navigate my ebooks as easily as the source `docx` or `htm`. I tried to follow instructions, changing the Calibre's settings for TOC, but this didn't help. Any suggestions?